# Issues to install packages in latest version of RStudio and R Versions (3.5.1 / 3.5.3)

Tags: r

I am unable to install packages (rtexttools and depend on maxent both lunch errors debt that the were removed recently from the CRAN repository) through latest version of RStudio and R Version.3.5.1 and 3.5.3.

I tried also installing them manually, format .tar, but nothing happened the the error remained.

The error:

> install.packages("RTextTools")
>
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/dramosd/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘RTextTools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages are not available to download via CRAN, In that case you can use below function to install R package directly from there github repo.

Try this-

```
library(devtools)
install_github("timjurka/RTextTools/RTextTools")
```

**Note- `RTextTools` is no longer actively maintained by developer. So, above method may not work.

Please check there website for more info-

http://www.rtexttools.com/install.html